# Download a file and then execute it

Tags: vb.net, download

I'm creating an application that downloads some applications (like FireFox, WinRar, RealPlayer) and then install them silently using Shell command. This is the code:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("URL", "path\file.exe")
Shell("path\file.exe /s")
```

The problem is that the shell command starts before Download Is completed, so I get a "file not found" error. So my questions are:

1. How can I execute Shell command after the download is completed?
2. Can I use process.start with `S` parameter instead of Shell command?

Comment: UAC was designed to stop you from doing this.  Windows 8's SmartScreen feature will put additional obstacles in your way.  Trying to work around these features designed to keep the user's machine safe and running is a very iffy proposition.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick to download the file and wait until its over:

```
Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
wc.DownloadFile(sURL, sFile)
```

Comment: It doesn't wait until download is over. Shell command is being executed before download is complete.

Comment: See [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx). "_This method blocks while downloading the resource_". I don't know what happens to you, maybe your URL its incorrect. It works for me.

Comment: Well , it works with process.start("File" , "Parameter") and so do the original statement . But I want to use Shell instead , have you tried it with Shell statement ?

Comment: This could help you: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/107422/shell-vs.-process.start-console-application

Comment: I know process.start is more flexible , but the problem is when it launches an application , it says do you want to run or cancel . Which can be annoying if used for many applications .